# Specify the range of a population in GA

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I would like to specify the range of a population generated by the Genetic Algorithm of the Optimization Toolbox of MATLAB:

```
function y= fitness_fct(x,L,R,score_initial)
    y=sqrt(power(((power(L,x(1)) +power(R,x(2))) -score_initial),2));  
    x(1) %here i see that the values are sometimes negative
end

for i=1:22    
    FitnessFunction =@(x) fitness_fct(x,L(i) ,R(i),score_initial(i));
    [x,fval] = ga(FitnessFunction,2);
end
```

In the documentation, the range is automatically set to [0;1] but practically it's not.

Comment: Do you want the initial population to be in that range, or must `x` always stay within [0;1] ?

Comment: x always belongs to the populations generated and i want it to stay within [0;1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by MATLAB documentation:

```
x = ga(fitnessfcn,nvars,A,b,Aeq,beq,LB,UB)
```

defines a set of lower and upper bounds on the design variables, 'x', so that a solution is found in the range 'LB ≤ x ≤ UB'.

Note: Set `Aeq=[]` and `beq=[]` if no linear equalities exist.

Example:
To solve the following inequality with given lower and upper boundaries:

[image]

The solution can be found as follows:

```
A = [1 1; -1 2; 2 1];
b = [2; 2; 3];
lb = zeros(2,1);
[x,fval,exitflag] = ga(@lincontest6,2,A,b,[],[],lb)
```

Here the code specifies only the lower bound, but you can easily define another vector for the upper bound. 
In your case `ub=ones(2,1)` and so:

```
[x,fval] = ga(FitnessFunction,2,[],[],[],[],lb,ub)
```

Comment: Ok, but in my case, what values will be putted in A and b ?

Comment: Set `A=[]` and `b=[]` if no linear inequalities exist.

Comment: yes i understand for the bounds, now i'm thinking if there is an equality in my case and how to model it considering have a "power" operator instead a multiplication. For example : L=[0.1595;0.1640;0.1790] and R=[0.4;0.2;0.5], 
 [L R] ^ [x(1);x(2)] <= ?. This is my problem now